# Firebase android auth, how to distinguish between login and register

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As we receive the login response onActivityResult as below

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    handleSignInResponse(data);
    return;
  }
  Timber.d(getString(R.string.unknown_response), requestCode);
  return;
}
```

How to distinguish whether it is new registered user or login user ?